# Как отсортировать двумерный массив по ключу?

Tags: php, массивы

Есть двумерный массив примерно такого вида

```
 array( 
        array('checkbox' => 1),
        array('checkbox' => 0),
        array('checkbox' => 1) 
         );
```

как можно массивы у которых checkbox = 1, поставить в начало массива? 
что бы было вот так:

```
array( 
            array('checkbox' => 1),
            array('checkbox' => 1),
            array('checkbox' => 0) 
             );
```

Comment: можно использовать функцию usort .

Answer (score 0):

К примеру, с помощью [arsort()](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.arsort.php):

```
$array = array(
    array('checkbox' => 1),
    array('checkbox' => 0),
    array('checkbox' => 1)
);

arsort($array);

var_dump($array);
```

Результат:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=1)
      'checkbox' => int 1
  2 => 
    array (size=1)
      'checkbox' => int 1
  1 => 
    array (size=1)
      'checkbox' => int 0
```